# Eclipse: sharing package between two projects for testing

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

The problem is that I use Mockito for testing a class with some protected methods. In order to mock them I need my tests to be in the same package.
I'm using the following scheme now:

project

---src

------some.package.for.class

---------MyClass.java

---tests //source folder

------some.package.for.class //so test package looks the same

---------Tests.java

It works, but the problem is that I don't trylly understand how. As I understand, BuildPath is part of Eclipse IDE, which help Eclipse to find files and libraries for my project.
So how is it possible to keep tests in other folder but in the same package???

And another question: is it possible to keep java files in one packages, yet in different projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to have class files in the same package but in different folders?  Yes.

Is it possible to have class files in the same package but in different projects? Yes.

When the classes load, they can come from many different places, including different JARs, but still be in the same package.

Regarding Eclipse, you just need to make sure you've selected all the source folders (including tests) in Java Build Path > Source.  There is no restriction that says all class files in the same package must be in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you! If I got it right: Build path is part of eclipse IDE, so if I try to compile .java files from command line using javac, it isn't able to use build.properites, and will find only those classes, which are follow the rules: folder structure should be the same as package structure.

Comment: @A.Provakov: you are correct, javac can't use the contents of build.properties, but you can specify other locations to search in for class files with the `-classpath` option. So to compile the tests from command line, use the `-classpath` option to point at the /bin diretory of your project.

Comment: @Soana: Thanks for explanation. Don't you accidentaly know any book, which will cover such topics like mechanism of JVM, class loaders, threads of execution? I'm learning java in process of internship, so in such moments I really sense a lack of fundamental knowledge about the language.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the [maven conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for source files
([Gradle](https://gradle.org/) adheres to many maven conventions too).

Therefore, I'd use:

- src/main/java/some/package/for/class/MyClass.java
- src/test/java/some/package/for/class/MyClassTest.java